# Cognito post authentication custom response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to return custom data in a AWS Cognito post-authentication lambda trigger?

I have tried setting properties in `event.response`, but these are not propagated back to the client.

For example:

```
module.exports.post_auth_trigger = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    event.response.some_custom_property = 'this is custom';
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Using this code does not return the `some_custom_property` to the client after authentication. How may this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. Check the response in [RespondToAuthChallenge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html#CognitoUserPools-RespondToAuthChallenge-response-ChallengeParameters). There is no element that could be used for passing custom data to client.

You will have to manually fire a new request after successful authentication.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks